# PHP-FPM (ZTS) service stuck on 'activating' but is working, then fails after 20 Minutes

Tags: php, service, ubuntu-22.04, fpm, zts

i have quite a weird problem with my php-fpm.service. I use Ubuntu 22.04 and I compiled PHP (ZTS) 7.4.33 and 8.0.26 from source with `--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2`, `--enable-parallel` and other Options successfully. Created the `phplib.so` and configured everything to work with Apache2. FPM is set to run in Socket-Mode

With 7.4 everything works great. I start the FPM service and Apache is processing PHP-Files.

However with 8.0 i got a weired Problem. When i use `systemctl --no-pager start php8.0-zts-fpm.service` it shows `Starting php8.0-zts-fpm (via systemctl): php8.0-zts-fpm.service` and hangs there until timeout.

So i tried `systemctl --no-pager --no-block start php8.0-zts-fpm.service` and checked Apache and php-info and everything works just like 7.4 (it shows version 8.0). fpm.log shows:

```
[31-Aug-2023 11:47:07] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 10674
[31-Aug-2023 11:47:07] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

but when i check the service-status i get:

```
● php8.0-zts-fpm.service - The PHP 8.0-zts FastCGI Process Manager
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php8.0-zts-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: activating (start) since Thu 2023-08-31 11:47:07 CEST; 6min ago
   Docs: man:php-fpm8.0-zts(8)
Main PID: 10674 (php-fpm)
  Tasks: 3 (limit: 4556)
 Memory: 43.0M
    CPU: 95ms
 CGroup: /system.slice/php8.0-zts-fpm.service
         ├─10674 "php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.0-zts/etc/php-fpm.conf)" "" "" "" "" "" ">
         ├─10680 "php-fpm: pool www" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
         └─10681 "php-fpm: pool www" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">

Aug 31 11:47:07 wayne-ubuntu-vmware systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 8.0-zts FastCGI Process Manager...
```

But still, everything works like it should. But after about 20 minutes, it fails:

```
× php8.0-zts-fpm.service - The PHP 8.0-zts FastCGI Process Manager
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php8.0-zts-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Thu 2023-08-31 11:04:33 CEST; 36min ago
   Docs: man:php-fpm8.0-zts(8)
Process: 8229 ExecStart=/etc/php/8.0-zts/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/8.0-z>
Process: 9490 ExecStopPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper remove /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc>
Main PID: 8229 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    CPU: 152ms

Aug 31 10:48:13 wayne-ubuntu-vmware systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 8.0-zts FastCGI Process Manager...
Aug 31 11:04:33 wayne-ubuntu-vmware systemd[1]: php8.0-zts-fpm.service: start operation timed out. >
Aug 31 11:04:33 wayne-ubuntu-vmware systemd[1]: php8.0-zts-fpm.service: Failed with result 'timeout>
Aug 31 11:04:33 wayne-ubuntu-vmware systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 8.0-zts FastCGI Process Man>
```

Configuration is the same for both versions. What did i get wrong? Any help would be apreciated. Thanks in advance!